# How to mak the image view rotate work like facebook's iOS app?

Tags: ios, rotation

In the main view of the Facebook app, if you click the image, the image view will pop-in and if you rotate the device, the rotation happens for the image-view.  But the main-view not.

My question is: if the pop-up imageview is subview of the main-view or main-window, how to make the subview rotation happen while the main-view not? It seems we can only make the whole  uiviewcontroller rotate or not, not sub-views, right?

Comment: you can listen to UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes @phix23 is correct. You can register your view controller as an observer for the deviceOrientationDidChange notification and handle the transform yourself. Alternatively, I think you can display your image view within its own view controller and make that a child of your main view controller. Then you can do whatever you like with the autorotation of the parent and child controllers independently

Comment: thanks, all, it works. and I find a link for the details http://the.ichibod.com/kiji/how-to-handle-device-rotation-for-uiviews-in-ios/